# Does the word "that" refer to "features" or "windows 9x"?

Tags: ambiguity, relative-clauses, relative-pronouns, antecedents

> Microsoft built a number of features into Windows 9x  that allow previous users of DOS and Windows 3.x  to capitalize on their investment and that allow technicians access to DOS-based troubleshooting.

Comment: What would be the difference in interpretation?

Comment: What would be the difference in interpretation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Both* instances of "that" refer back to the *specific features* alluded to at the beginning of the sentence when it says "a number of features".

Microsoft built a number of features into Windows 9x **that** allow previous users of DOS and Windows 3.x to capitalize on their investment and **that** allow technicians access to DOS-based troubleshooting.

If there were no mention of the "features", you wouldn't need "that", see this example:

> Microsoft Windows 9x allows users to.... and technicians to....

But:

> Windows 9x *has features that* allow users to... and technicians to...

Comment: You’d also see “allows” (*-s* case agreement with singular “Windows 9x”) instead of “allow”, as your counter-example has it. I wonder if the confusion is in part not recognizing that “Windows 9x” is grammatically singular, despite appearances.

Comment: So it isn't a requirement that the word "that" refers to the noun immediately preceding it, isn't it?

Comment: @AmrMahmoud No - for example "I have a car parked in my garage that is red". The car is red, not the garage.

Comment: Thanks for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: @Astralbee's example illustrates "that" pretty well. If you wanted to talk about the garage instead, you could write "I have a car parked in my garage, which is red."

Answer (score 3):

Let's address this in a very simple manner. Remove *into Windows 9x* from the sentence. Let us withhold the subject (Windows 9x in this case) for a moment. Does the sentence still make sense? Does the sentence satisfy subject-verb agreement? If it does, like in this case, then **that** refers to 'number of features'.

Let me emphasize on the usage of **allow** and **that** here. If the sentence corresponded to *Windows 9x*, then *that* would have changed to *which*—mostly between commas as an explanation of what Windows 9x is—and *allow* would have been changed to *allows*, to satiate subject-verb agreement.